# Migrating Django regex URL pattern to Pyramid URL Dispatch

Tags: python, regex, django, pyramid

I'm new with regex and pyramid and I have the following URLs in DJango that I need to translate to Pyramid:

```
DOWNLOAD_XFORM = "download_xform"
LIST_XFORMS = "list_xforms"
FORM_LIST = "form_list"

OPT_GROUP_REGEX = "((?P<group_name>[^/]+)/)?"

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^%sformList$" % OPT_GROUP_REGEX, views.formList, name=FORM_LIST),
    url(r"^%ssubmission$" % OPT_GROUP_REGEX, views.submission),
    url(r"^%sxform/new/$" % OPT_GROUP_REGEX, views.create_xform),
    url(r"^%sxform/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)\.xml$" % OPT_GROUP_REGEX, views.download_xform, name=DOWNLOAD_XFORM),
    url(r"^xform/toggle_downloadable/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/$", views.toggle_downloadable),
    url(r"^submission_test_form/?$", views.submission_test_form),
    url(r"^xform/(?P<id_string>[^/]+)/$", views.update_xform),
    url(r"^%s$" % OPT_GROUP_REGEX, views.list_xforms, name=LIST_XFORMS),
    url(r"^survey/(?P<pk>\d+)/$", views.instance),)
```

I saw in the documentation that you have have something like:

```
config.add_route('myroute', '/prefix/{foo:[^/]+}')
```

But I have trouble migrating bits like:

```
url(r"^%sformList$" % OPT_GROUP_REGEX, views.formList, name=FORM_LIST),
```

Any idea would be appreciated

Comment: Can you give an example what the final URL should look like in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know a lot about migrating. But for digit url dispatch regex you can use

```
config.add_route('home', '/{number_id:\d+}')
```

*from documentation